# Is there a way to filter UltraGrids based on the value of 2 columns?

Tags: c#, winforms, infragistics, ultrawingrid

Say I have an Infragistic `UltraGrid` with columns *Foo* and *Bar*. Is it possible to filter the table so that only rows where *Foo* and *Bar* are not equal are displayed?

For instance, if I had this data:

```
Foo  Bar
--------
0.1  0.1
0.1  0.2
0.2  0.2
```

The filter would hide the first and the third row.

Comment: In the latest samples, the UltraGridFilterUIProvider control seems to be able to do the filtering using different columns. The sample is called `Excel Style Filtering`

Comment: @zneak How are you looking to expose this through the UI since the UI of the grid doesn't provide this by default?  If you are adding your own button or option external to the grid on the form, then it will be simpler to filter the DataTable rather than the grid.  In this example you would set the RowFilter on the DefaultView of the DataTable. For example if your DataTable is fooData you would use the follwoing: 

fooData.DefaultView.RowFilter = "Foo <> Bar";

Comment: @alhalama, I would not expose it through the UI. It would not be possible for users to toggle this filter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is simplier than it seems and i am sure you do not have to create additional column or something:

```
UltraGridColumn fooColumn = Grid.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns["Foo"];
UltraGridColumn barColumn = Grid.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns["Bar"];
ColumnFilter fooColumnFilter = fooColumn.Band.ColumnFilters[fooColumn];
fooColumnFilter.ClearFilterConditions();
fooColumnFilter.FilterConditions.Add(FilterComparisionOperator.NotEquals, barColumn);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the solution.  Do you happen to know if this can also be done in the designer?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this from the Grid designer;

1. Create a new Boolean column with Formula `[Foo]!=[Bar]` to your data source.
2. Add the hidden column to your grid and set your grid's `DisplayLayout.Override.RowFilterMode = RowFilterMode.AllRowsInBand`.
3. In the `grid.DisplayLayout.Band[].ColumnFilters`, add a new `FilterLogicalOperator.And` with the new column's `FilterConditions.Add(FilterComparisionOperator.Equals, true)`.

Comment: I'm using a binding source attached to a `DataTable`. Would it work to add an unbound column to the UltraGrid?

Comment: I don't think one can act on unbound columns from the Grid designer, @zneak, you may be able to do this programmatically. I do not think you can define a `FilterCondition` that uses values from multiple columns, hence my suggestion to create a new column saying whether the values are unequal and filter on that.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to use an unbound column. You can set the value in the InitializeRow event.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not allowing users to toggle this filter and are using a DataTable, the simplest solution is to filter the DataTable rather than the grid.

For example if your DataTable is fooData you would use the follwoing:

```
fooData.DefaultView.RowFilter = "Foo <> Bar";
```

Comment: Huh, now that I went back to the code, I realized that one of the columns is unbound.

Comment: If one of the columns is an unbound column, then you may need to use the approach that Jeff Bridgman suggested or modify your DataTable before binding the grid to include the additional column.